# Variable PATH in shell using cron

Tags: shell, cron

I've read that while using a **cron** you define variables like always:

```
var = <value>
```

But you can't use variable values on < value > such as:

```
PATH=$PATH
```

So how could I introduce the PATH inside PATH plus HOME/FOLDER for instance? Normally I would do...

```
PATH=$HOME/FOLDER:$PATH
```

But if what I've read is correct, that isn't available...right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my [crontab(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/crontab.5.html) page agrees with you:

> The  value  string  is  **not** parsed for environmental substitutions or replacement of variables, thus lines     like
>
> > ```
> > PATH = $HOME/bin:$PATH
> > ```
>
> will not work as you might expect.

However, if you're specifically interested in `$HOME`, you can use this:

> An alternative for setting up the commands path is using the fact that many shells will treat the tilde(~)  as substitution of $HOME, so if you use bash for your tasks you can use this:
>
> > ```
> > SHELL=/bin/bash
> > PATH=~/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin
> > ```